Fastapi's `TestClient`' fails with SSE response
I'm currently doing unit-tests with a fastapi service using pytest. I found that fastapi.testclient.TestClient can only handle one post request and subsequent call to TestClient.post would fail. Here is an minimum reproducible example:
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from fastapi import FastAPI
from sse_starlette import EventSourceResponse


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/hello")
def query_hello_1():
    def hello():
        yield "hello"
    return EventSourceResponse(
        hello(),
    )


@app.post("/hello_2")
def query_hello_2():
    def hello():
        yield "hello_2"
    return EventSourceResponse(
        hello(),
    )


client = TestClient(app)


def test_hello_1():
    print(list(client.post("/hello").iter_lines()))


def test_hello_2():
    print(list(client.post("/hello_2").iter_lines()))



Run this script with pytest gives  raise RuntimeError(f'{self!r} is bound to a different event loop') error for the second test. But it is perfectly ok if I just return a plain text instead of an SSE response. I wonder if there is a better approach to test apis with SSE response using TestClient?

I'm guessing since you're calling endpoints which keep a connection open and send data as it arrives, you'll have to explicitly close it by calling .close() on the client. You can do this in a fixture to avoid having to remember it between tests (this would probably also work as you expect if you define client as a fixture, instead of having a global client you re-use in tests, since it gets stuck in a state where it expects data instead of being re-initialized). I recommend creating a new test client in a fixture instead of re-using it.

@MatsLindh Hi, I tried to add client. close() at the end of each test, but the same error occurred. Regarding the fixure approach, could you please give me an example of how to do it since I haven't worked with it before.

Create a function named client that yield TestClient. Decore the function with @pytest.fixture, then add client as a parameter to your test_.. function. This argument will now automagically be filled by pytest with the yielded value from the function name that matches the parameter name: https://docs.pytest.org/en/8.2.x/explanation/fixtures.html#what-fixtures-are

@MatsLindh I'm afraid pytest.fixture doesn't work, it gives the same error...

Using this fixture solves your issue:

@pytest.fixture
def reset_sse_starlette_appstatus_event():
    """
    Fixture that resets the appstatus event in the sse_starlette app.

    Should be used on any test that uses sse_starlette to stream events.
    """
    # See https://github.com/sysid/sse-starlette/issues/59
    from sse_starlette.sse import AppStatus

    AppStatus.should_exit_event = None

Hope this helps!
